# SAPUI5 Date mismatch in oData

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I am passing date from `sap.m.DatePicker` to oData service filter. I have used JSON model bound to date picker to access the date chosen by the user.

My issue is: When I choose `1st Oct 2018` as the date, I see the date as `30th Sep 2018` (20180930 as per SAP backend format) in debug session. It is always going 1 date behind in Gateway oData service.

What has gone wrong here!!

I tried various approaches like `date.setHours(0,0,0,0), date.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)` etc from front end. But my issue was never resolved. I guess it is something with respect to timezone.

Can someone please guide me what is the issue here.

Comment: Could you show me the binding on your DatePicker ? Have you tried setting the format options to UTC:true ? 
{path: 'YourModelPath', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime', constraints: {displayFormat: 'Date'}, formatOptions: {UTC: true}}

Comment: which odata version do you use? which type is your date property in the oData call?

Comment: Tried this, however, it did not work out. 

I have entered the date range as follows:
01.10.2018 - 12.10.2018

In browser debugger, I can see these dates when printed in console as:
Mon Oct 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
Fri Oct 12 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

which is correct..
However, it is received as 20180930 and 20181011 in oData!!

The result remains same with UTC:true and UTC:false

Comment: Code used is:

<DateRangeSelection id="idDateRangeSelection" displayFormat="dd.MM.yyyy" dateValue="{path: 'filterHeaderModel>/fromDate', 
constraints: {displayFormat: 'Date'}, formatOptions: {UTC: true}}" secondDateValue="{path: 'filterHeaderModel>/toDate', constraints: {displayFormat: 'Date'}, formatOptions: {UTC: true}}" 
 change="onDateFilterChange" placeholder="Select Date Range"/>

Later, it is accessed from controller as:
   var dFrom = oFilterHeaderModel.getProperty("/fromDate");
   var dTo = oFilterHeaderModel.getProperty("/toDate");

Comment: Edm.Datetime is the oData datatype
oData version is 2

Comment: What are the timezones of your browser and your backend server ?
In which format is the timestamp stored in the backend server ?
Is only the date stored in the backend, without any reference to time or timezone ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue with transfering Dates back to the backend. This happens because the time of the date is midnight and a conversion according to time zone takes place when submitting the date to the backend system. A work around could be to set the hours of the date object to 12 before submitting the object as a filter value.